# Spacing & sizing with libertine and newtxmath

Tags: fonts, spacing, libertine, kerning, newtx

I'm using the following setup for the Libertine font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lining]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine, cmintegrals]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Test: $75 + 250\log_2 n = 75 + \frac{250}{\log_{10} 2} \log_{10} n$

\end{document}
```

But the spacing for inline math seems to be a little strange:

[image]

Compare the spacing of `=` and the numbers in the denominator to the output with `mathpazo` or `mathdesign`/Utopia:

[image]
[image]

In my opinion the Libertine results look more uneven and poorly spaced. Is this just how the font looks, or is there something I can do to make this look better?

Comment: I agree that libertine looks suboptimal here (or is newtxmath to blame?). The "10" in the logarithms looks particularly bad, maybe the numbers are drawn from the wrong place  (tabular figures).

Comment: Check your log. I can't duplicate your output.

Comment: @user22108 Added MWE. It's very simplistic and exhibits the same spacing as my original screenshot.

Comment: In my test, I added \huge; so it seems the small size is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The answer here I'm afraid is that this is 'how it is': spacing for fonts is a property of the font. You could feedback to the maintainers of the various fonts to see if the spacing can be changed, but beyond that there is not much to do other than choose some other combination.

Comment: The good news -- speaking specifically about the choice `\usepackage[libertine, cmintegrals]{newtxmath}` -- is that in the ca 18 months since the query was posted some corrections have occurred. If one runs the OP's MWE now, the output looks much better. This, of course, doesn't impinge on the validity of your observation that when it comes to fonts, "this is how it is" applies.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I'd noticed things looked different :-)